# Canvas HTML5: Display rect coordinates on mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently developing an image editor with **HTML5 Canvas**, and I'm having a problem detecting the image coordinates when mousing over the canvas.

I have replicated the problem in a code snipped with a rectangle:

[image: Example]

When:

- The red part is the border of the canvas. The canvas size is **400x400 pixels**.
- The green part is a rectangle simulating the image. The rect size is **200x200 pixels**.
- On the mousemove event, is displaying at the bottom coordinates of the canvas.
- The blue text, is what I want (right now the coordinates are not those, are of the canvas)

What I want and I don't know how to do it:

- On mousemove, I want to display **coordinates of the rect** instead of the canvas coordinates. ie the `(0, 0)` of the canvas will become negative. And the displayed `(0, 0)` on the bottom should correspond with the blue text.
- It **should work also after changing the ZOOM** property. The ZOOM in the example is `1`, but after changing to `0.5` or `1.5` should work in the same way.

#### Code

Here below I share the code snipped to see if anyone can help me with that because I'm a little frustrated and I'm sure it's silly. Thanks a lot!

```js
const RECT_SIZE = 200
const ZOOM = 1
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const svgPoint = svg.createSVGPoint()
const xform = svg.createSVGMatrix()
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const res = document.querySelector('.res')
const pt = transformedPoint(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
const X = canvas.width / 2 - RECT_SIZE / 2
const Y = canvas.height / 2 - RECT_SIZE / 2

function transformedPoint(x, y) {
  svgPoint.x = x
  svgPoint.y = y
  return svgPoint.matrixTransform(xform.inverse())
}

function mousemove(e) {
  const { left, top } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  res.textContent = `X: ${e.clientX - left} - Y: ${e.clientY - top}`
}

// SCALING CANVAS
ctx.translate(pt.x, pt.y)
ctx.scale(ZOOM, ZOOM)
ctx.translate(-pt.x, -pt.y)

// SETTING SOME DEFAULTS
ctx.lineWidth = 1
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green'
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'

// DRAWING A REACTANGLE
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.strokeRect(X, Y, RECT_SIZE,  RECT_SIZE)

ctx.font = "12px Arial";
ctx.fillText("0,0", X - 5, Y-10);
ctx.fillText("200,200", X + RECT_SIZE - 15, Y + RECT_SIZE + 15);

ctx.closePath()
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" onmousemove="mousemove(event)"}></canvas>
<div class="res" />
```

Changing the line:

```js
res.textContent = `X: ${e.clientX - left} - Y: ${e.clientY - top}`
```

to

```js
res.textContent = `X: ${e.clientX - left - X} - Y: ${e.clientY - top - Y}`
```

Is displaying the correct coordinates when `ZOOM = 1`. However, is not displaying the correct coordinates after change the zoom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add ZOOM value to the X and Y calculation like in the example below. I used Math.round method as the final X and Y value is a long fraction.

```js
const RECT_SIZE = 200
const ZOOM = 1.4
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const svgPoint = svg.createSVGPoint()
const xform = svg.createSVGMatrix()
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const res = document.querySelector('.res')
const pt = transformedPoint(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
const X = canvas.width / 2 - RECT_SIZE / 2;
const Y = canvas.height / 2 - RECT_SIZE / 2;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',(event)=>{
  const {top, left} = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const zoomX = Math.round((event.clientX - left - (canvas.width / 2 - ((RECT_SIZE * ZOOM) / 2)))/ZOOM);
  const zoomY = Math.round((event.clientY - top - (canvas.height / 2 - ((RECT_SIZE * ZOOM) / 2)))/ZOOM);
  res.textContent = `X: ${zoomX} - Y: ${zoomY}`;

});

function transformedPoint(x, y) {
  svgPoint.x = x
  svgPoint.y = y
  return svgPoint.matrixTransform(xform.inverse())
}


// SCALING CANVAS
ctx.translate(pt.x, pt.y)
ctx.scale(ZOOM, ZOOM)
ctx.translate(-pt.x, -pt.y)

// SETTING SOME DEFAULTS
ctx.lineWidth = 1
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green'
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'

// DRAWING A REACTANGLE
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.strokeRect(X, Y, RECT_SIZE,  RECT_SIZE)

ctx.font = "12px Arial";
ctx.fillText("0,0", X - 5, Y-10);
ctx.fillText("200,200", X + RECT_SIZE - 15, Y + RECT_SIZE + 15);

ctx.closePath()
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"}></canvas>
<div class="res" />
```